# Possible to have "mouseover for X seconds" functionality using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have several elements in a row that have a mouseover event that fires some animation.  My problem is that if someone mouses over several of the elements in quick succession the animation gets a little frantic.

I'm curious if there is a way to have a mouseover event that only fires if the mouse is over an element for a certain amount of time (say 250 milliseconds).  Can this be done with jQuery?

Comment: `stop()` can be an alternative and you're not constrained to download any plug-ins, have a look at it (http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: How would I use stop to do this?

Comment: edit your post and stamp the code that handle elements' event, I'll see if you can use this in your code and will post an example as an answer to your trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you use setTimeout for this:

```
(function ($) {
    var t;
    $('ul li').hover(function() {
        var that = this;
        window.clearTimeout(t);
        t = window.setTimeout(function () {
            $(that).animate({opacity: .5}, 'slow').animate({opacity: 1});
          }, 250);
    });
}(jQuery));
```

If there are multiple items activated in rapid succession the timeout will override the timeout-id thus preventing the first item that should not start from animating.

It does not require any arcane plugin (although hoverIntent may provide some nice additional features you may want to use) and [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) is supported everywhere.

**UPDATE**

I updated the code sample to work.. was writing this from memory yesterday and didn't get the setTimeout call quite right.. Also see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tigraine/dyFDC/) for reference.

The issue I see with this is that it will execute the hover animation even if you leave the . So you could also add a `$('ul').mouseleave(function() { window.clearTimeout(t) });` to prevent that.

greetings Daniel

Comment: I like the idea of a solution with no plugin.  Unfortunately I have not been able to get solutions using setTimeout to work.  I'll keep playing with it and see if I can get something going.

Comment: Now it works as advertised.. was writing this yesterday without checking the code..

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you check out the jQuery HoverIntent plugin ( 1.4k minified ). Here's the link: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html. It's a great plugin, I've used it many times!

Here's a small sampling of code:

```
var config = {    
     over: makeTall, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
     timeout: 500, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
     out: makeShort // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)    
};

$("#demo3 li").hoverIntent( config )
```

Comment: Ha! Beat me to it by 2 seconds. :-)

Comment: Deleted in the name of honor.

Comment: Unnecessary use of a plugin. The OPs problem can be easily solved with 8-10 lines of code without having to load yet another JavaScript file..

Comment: @Tigraine, I think you should re-read SO's "When should I down-vote" criteria - http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down. `Whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect, vote it down!`. Your down-vote is based on preference. This is a viable solution, and one that many others would gladly use.

Comment: I'd argue my down-vote is not based on preference but I'll refrain from posting the thousands of articles saying you should a) keep complexity low b) not include thousands of JS files into your site to keep it fast..

Answer (score 1):

yes:
to accomplish this put a `setTimeout` in your onMouseover function and a `clearTimeout` on mouseout

You may need a little more logic, but that's the nuts and bolts of it

Answer (score 0):

here's an example of `stop()` in action, hope that will help:

without `stop()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/5djzM/

with `stop()` cleaning the queue of animations:

http://jsfiddle.net/KjybD/

Comment: Hrrm, I still don't see how I can use `stop` to delay things.

Comment: it doesn't delay anything, it's just sweeping off the animation stack of jQuery, I thought you've had troubles with animations stressing the cursor on several elements. `stop` is often used to round this problem (btw let me know have you stressed the cursor on the menu in examples that I wrote ? try both)